# Log in issue after after deploying .Net Core 3.1 web app to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, model-view-controller

I created a .Net Core 3.1 MVC application that is using induvial user accounts as authentication.  I deployed the site to IIS, which works.  However when I tried to log in with an account I know that works, the login does not succeed, and I am directed back the default route of the application. No error messages or log entries that I can find. The application pool is set up for non managed code, and is running under an account that has dbo rights to the database.  Any thoughts as to what the issue might be?

Comment: According to your description, you have used asp.net core identity as the authentication mode. The identity will use the connection string to get the user information. I suggest you could firstly check you have used the right database from connection string in your server's IIS folder. If you used the different connection string, that means you used different database. All the user you have created in the develop environment will not work after you have published the application to the IIS.

Comment: Thanks Brando.  The json file on the IIS site has the same connection string,  I restarted my server last night and now it works.  Not sure sure why the reboot fixed it, however things are working as expected.

Comment: I'm glad you have solved the issue by yourself. Please mark it as answer and this will help other folks who faces the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot has fixed the issue.  I had installed the .Net core run times on the server, so prehaps a restart was needed.